# Can I use a private library to share dependencies between projects?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a private library that I use internally between all my apps to reduce boilerplate and annoying parts of Android framework.

I'm wondering *if* and *how* can I use it to share libraries that I use in all my projects.

For example I use leakcanary everywhere in my apps:

```
debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7"
implementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:plumber-android:2.7"
```

Can I move it to my private library like this:

```
debugApi "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7"
api "com.squareup.leakcanary:plumber-android:2.7"
```

Will it now be correctly included in all my apps that use this private library since I used `api`? What about the dependency I include using the "runtimeOnly" or "kapt" keywords?

For example with `hilt`

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

**I know the question about api and implementation keywords have already been asked multiple time on stackoverflow. But after reading the answer (along with the documentation), I still feel like I don't understand how all of this work. Please consider this before closing my question with just a link to an answer I've already read.**

Comment: Did you try this? I have the feeling it would take you less than 1 hour of coding to verify most of your questions. Create your library, add the dependencies and try it? By the looks of the stuff you're talking about, you don't seem like a "junior" developer on Android, so what's stopping you from testing this?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I gave up on trying it by myself because it is more complicated that it seems at first. You can add the "api" and "debugApi" for leakcanary but you also need the corresponding "apply plugin". Also the build cache can make it tricky to play with "runtimeOnly" and "kapt" and may give you fake results if you don't full clear the cache every time ... so I was hopping someone already got an answer to this.

Comment: Makes sense. Well, I haven't tried this, so unfortunately I do not have an answer, I was hoping you were going to answer it yourself and post your results :)